# My SQL triggers

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

Is it possible to set up a mysql trigger that fires back the id number of that record when ever there is an insert into  the database AND  how do i capture that using php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I don't fully understand your question, you don't need a trigger for this - just use the "last inserted ID" functionality of your database driver.

Here's an example using the basic mysql driver in PHP.

```
<?php

$db = mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'user', 'pass' );

$result = mysql_query( "insert into table (col1, col2) values ('foo', 'bar')", $db );

$lastId = mysql_insert_id();
```

This is a connection-safe way to obtain the ID.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the previous answers, you'd don't need to use a trigger to return the identity.  You can use the mysql_insert_id() command as described in the [documentation][1].

However if you need to use the new insert id in a trigger, use NEW.[identity_column_name] as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE temp (
    temp_id int auto_increment,
    value varchar(10),
    PRIMARY_KEY(temp_id)
);

CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_temp AFTER INSERT ON temp
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @identity;
    SET @identity = NEW.temp_id;
    -- do something with @identity
END
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're asking.  Are you wanting to insert a row into the database and get the id it was assigned too?  If so do this

printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a trigger to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Simply calling PHP's `mysql_insert_id` will return the ID generated from the last INSERT query executed.

Described here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php